# .htaccess Pretty URLs title in url

Tags: php, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting, pretty-urls

I'm trying to make pretty url but want to put content title in url instead id, then i put content title in url with query string:

> index.php?action=content&id=22

**changed to:**

> index.php?action=content&title=stack-over-flow

it's works fine. now i trying to make it pretty but got a problem in htaccess code.

before removing id in url code was:

```
RewriteRule ^([a-z]+)/([0-9]+)/?$ index.php?action=$1&id=$2 [NC,L,QSA]
```

**then i changed to:**

```
RewriteRule ^([a-z]+)/([a-z]+)/?$ content.php?action=$1&title=$2 [NC,L,QSA]
```

but it's not working and i will back **300 Multiple Choices** page. well, i think it's a httaccess problem, but i'm new in htaccess, need a hand to fix this.

**want this:**

> /content/stack-over-flow

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your regex is only allowing letters. It should also allow hyphen, numbers, upper case letters and underscore. Try this:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^([a-z]+)/([^/]+)/?$ content.php?action=$1&title=$2 [NC,L,QSA]
```

Comment: just one question. it works when title is english, for non english title i got 300 multiple choices page again. it get non english character like this: /content/ÙØ±ÙˆØ´Ú¯Ø§Ù‡-Ø¬Ø¯ÛŒØ¯-Ú¯ÙˆÚ¯Ù„ what about this?